# C# asp.net button click does not display label

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, label

I'm creating a simple bill calculator. When the bill button is clicked, a label will display the total. For some reason the button does not do anything. I'm not getting any errors in my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
    protected void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Validate();
    if (IsValid)
    {
    }

    decimal tips = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTips.Text);
    decimal meals = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMeals.Text);
    decimal buffets = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBuffets.Text);
    string fname = txtFirstName.Text;
    string tnumber = txtTableNumber.Text;
    decimal mealsvalue = meals * 16.99M;
    decimal buffetsvalue = buffets * 11.5M;
    decimal tax = 0;
    decimal walkR = 0;
    decimal phoneR = 0;

    if (rblTax.SelectedValue == "Tax")
    {
       tax = .06M;
    }
    else
    {
    }


    if (rblReservation.SelectedValue == "Walk-in")
    {
        decimal subtotal = walkR + mealsvalue + buffetsvalue;
        decimal taxvalue = subtotal * tax;
        decimal total = walkR + mealsvalue + buffetsvalue + taxvalue + tips;
        lblSummary.Text = "First name is " + fname + " Table number is " + tnumber + " Walk in cost is " + walkR + " Cost of meals is " + mealsvalue +
        " Cost of buffets is " + buffetsvalue + " Tax is " + taxvalue + " Tip is " + tips + " Total is " + total;
    }
    else if (rblReservation.SelectedValue == "Phone")
    {
        phoneR = 3;
        decimal subtotal = phoneR + mealsvalue + buffetsvalue;
        decimal taxvalue = subtotal * tax;
        decimal total = phoneR + mealsvalue + buffetsvalue + tax + tips;
        lblSummary.Text = "First name is " + fname + " Table number is " + tnumber + " Phone reservation cost is " + phoneR + " Cost of meals is " + mealsvalue +
        " Cost of buffets is " + buffetsvalue + " Tax is " + tax + " Tip is " + tips + " Total is " + total;
    }
    else
    {
        lblSummary.Text = "Please fill out the information";
    }
}
```

button declaration

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalc" runat="server" Text="Bill" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSummary" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Strongsad, don't you need something like onserverclick="the_name_of_your_method" in the button declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like OnClick is missing in your ASP.NET section of code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalc" runat="server" Text="Bill" OnClick="btnCalc_Click"/>
```

Updated:

To fix the other issue, instead of converting to decimal, try parsing as shown below,

```
decimal tips = 0;
bool result = decimal.TryParse(txtTips.Text, out tips);

if (result)
{
 //txtTips.Text has a valid decimal value. You can proceed with your logic.
}
```

Comment: I added that, but now it says FormatException was unhandled by user code and input string was not in a correct format on this line: decimal tips = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTips.Text);

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the solution as accepted answer so that others will not spend time in answering this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the Button declaration which event handler to use.
In this case the event handler is `OnClick` and the event function is `btnCalc_Click`.

Either add OnClick event in your button declaration like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalc" runat="server" Text="Bill" OnClick="btnCalc_Click" />
```

OR

Provide event to your button using C# code in `page_load` event like this.

```
btnCalc.Click += btnCalc_Click;
```

Comment: I added that, but now it says FormatException was unhandled by user code and input string was not in a correct format on this line: decimal tips = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTips.Text);

Comment: That is another problem, not related to your original question. However, to answer that, can you please tell me what do you enter in txtTips TextBox? Do you leave it empty?